# JWT refresh token in React+NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt

working on a small project and got some authentication going on with jwt tokens, the whole procedure looks like this:

1. Generate jwt token on auth/register along with a refreshToken
2. Make requests with the token
3. If the token is expired, I query the requesting user and his refreshToken, comparing his current request refreshToken and database token
4. If tokens match, I generate a new token and a new refresh token.

The whole problem is 5th step, lets say i make a request to "/me/friends" and along the way my token expires, I then make a new one out of my refreshToken, but I do not understand how should I return the token back to front-end on "me/friends" api call as it returns an array of specific fields and token has nothing to do with it. I just cant get my head around on how this is supposed to work, can anyone assist me please?

Comment: You should try to use middlewares, in any call from your front you 'll have a middelware that call the endpoint to refresh your token

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing your token on the client side?  The easiest method is to just store it in a cookie.  In that case, Step 5 just becomes setting an updated cookie with the request.

Another option is to return a 401-Unauthorized from your endpoint, then on the client side you can handle a 401 status code by trying to refresh the token manually and then retrying the request.

But I think option 1 is preferable if you're not using some sort of authentication middleware that doesn't hit the endpoint at all if auth is expired.

Comment: I am using localStorage to store the token. And I'm using passport package for middleware, got a strategy going on before all of the requests. I've seen tutorials making endpoints to /token , but how does that work?..